# How to Stop the binding when the controls are initializing in the DOM

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, html-select

I'm having a question about knockout binding to a select list. the problem is if we attached a click binding to a control, the event will be executed whenever the control is clicked. but why this select change event is firing while the control is loading to the DOM. I'm using knockout for last three week. this is the fiddle for that. 
      http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/dUvRx/4/

```
 <select data-bind='options :list, optionsText: "name", value:selectedItem , event : { change : onSelectChange }'></select>

  var model = function(){
  var self = this;

  self.name = ko.observable();
  self.key = ko.observable();

  self.visible = ko.observable();

  self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

 self.onSelectChange = function(data,event){
    var currentSelection = self.selectedItem();
    if(currentSelection.visible  )
     {
      // display the content according to the selection
     }
  }
 };

 ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

please help me to sort this problem.

I don't want to use the optionsCaption to select the default item. because the collection is coming from a ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onSelectChange` method is based off of the values of the select box. Thus, when the value changes as a result of the data binding (such as when the items are first added to the list), it is correct for this event to fire.

Instead of basing your change event off of the select box, it might be better to base your change event off of the data-bound properties.

First, you could change your list to be an observable array.

```
list = ko.observableArray([{ name : "test-01", key : 1, visible: true},
   { name : "test-02", key : 2 , visible: false},
   { name : "test-03", key : 3 , visible: false},
   { name : "test-04", key : 4 , visible: true}
]);

selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

In your markup:

```
<select data-bind='options :list, optionsText: "name", value:selectedItem'></select>
```

Now, whenever you want to determine if the item has changed, you can use the `ko.subscribe` function.

```
selectedItem.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* Do stuff when the value changes here */ });
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, is there any other way to get the selected value from a select box rather than assigning a value property? I can understand knockout binds the control whenever the value changes immediately. like other input controls text,button etc, the events will fires when the attached event handlers are called. if i remove value binding from the select box, then the change event will work whenever the user select a options from the select box, rather than initial stage. but the issue is how can i get the currently selected value?

Comment: You get or set the current option using the value binding. With my sample case, if, at any time you want to get the current selection for the select, you can simply say `selectedItem()`. This will return the currently selected object in the `option` binding. This page describes everything about using `<select>` elements with Knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Basically, once you set up the data-bindings, you will only need to interact with the observables. Adding/removing elements to the select will require adding/removing elements from the observable array (your `list` variable). Getting/setting the selection of the select will be done through the `selectedItem` observable. Subscriptions to change events can be done using the `selectedItem` as well. That is all you should really need.

Comment: Ok I understood, if i added a event binding to a select list(eg: change) when i event  fires how can i get the currently selected item? see this fiddle from rayn http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LBz6d/ he has done that using subscriptions and event, from the chnage event binding how do we get the selected value?

Comment: You would not use the event { change } binding. In order to get the event when the list selection changes, you will call `selectedItem.subscribe(function(newValue) { /* Do stuff when the value changes here */ });` The function will be called every time the value changes, and the single parameter (`newValue` in this case) will contain the value of the selected item.

Comment: Just to clarify, the reason for using only the observables; since you're using Knockout, you need to let Knockout do all of the hard work. You don't need to worry about subscribing to the selectionChange event. It's unnecessary, because Knockout does that for you when you data-bind the `value` to `selectedItem`. It is a convenience for you.

Comment: The problem for me is I'm fetching the list from a ajax call, when the list is bind to the select, I'm showing some contents according to the selected Item. but when the select is loaded into the DOM, the selected item is already selected and content will be shown automatically. how can i tell knockout to  stop the binding in the initial stage?

Comment: Changing what is represented in the `list` should have no effect on the events fired when the `selectedItem` changes. Can you maybe show a JSFiddle for what you're describing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30079/discussion-between-asn-and-patrick-d)

Comment: Where's the chat? I need some closure here!